# How to use Q promises in ExpressJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, node.js-connect

I need to generate pdf docs. All magic about pdf going in `generateDoc` func which return promise with Buffer data as a param. But Express doesn't send data to the client, only header. What am I doing wrong?

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
        generateDoc().then(function(data) {
            res.set({
                'Content-Type': 'application/pdf',
                'Content-Length': data.length
            });
            res.end(data);
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solution**:

If you want to return from server pdf, you must use `binary` param for res.end.

```
generateDoc().then(function(data) {
    res.set({
        'Content-Type': 'application/pdf',
        'Content-Length': data.length
    });
    res.end(data, 'binary');
}).fail(function (error) {
    res.end(500, "Some error");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `res.send` ([ref](http://expressjs.com/api.html#res.send)):

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    generateDoc().then(function(data) {
        ...
        res.send(data);
    });
});
```

Comment: @NiLL, any errors? `data` not empty, you sure? what does `generateDoc().then(function(data) { console.log(arguments)` show?

Comment: Just empty body, no one error and correct headers. But without content-type, data handles correct.

Answer (score 0):

I use this:

```
server.get('/item/:id', function (req, res, next) {
    service.get(req.params.id).
    done(res.json.bind(res), next);
});
```

Call the `done` method to execute the promise chain. Use the `next` callback function as an error handler so that the error gets sent to the client! Be sure to bind the `json` method to the `res` object to prevent an error.